# Batch File: List all files in directory with sequentially with indentation

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am new to writing batch files and I am trying to implement the output file to be like this:

```
C:\
---Folder1
      ---files
      ---files
---Folder2
      ---files
I also want the path of each file
```

Tried using /tree but I need the output in a text file. I do not want to use /tree because the lines will appear. I want to parse the files into a data frame. Hence I do not want any symbols or arrows. I need to use whitespaces.

Comment: What's wrong with the output from the `tree` command? Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `tree /?` to read its usage information.

Comment: I want to store it in a text file. When I use /tree the arrows are not displayed in text file.

Comment: So example `Tree "C:\BaseFolder" /F > "D:\results.txt"` or `Tree "C:\BaseFolder" /A /F > "D:\results.txt"` didn't produce output similar to your shown example?

Comment: It gives a different output. Instead of the arrows I am getting a font like AAAA and 333.

Comment: I do not want to use /tree because the lines will appear. I want to parse the files to create an excel file where each indentation value is belongs to a particular column.

Comment: Well I'd suggest you stop commenting, press on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58068603/edit) button under your question, and formulate a more accurate question.

Comment: `tree` works fine in a text file. The issue is how you're displaying it. Open it in Notepad, and change the font to `Terminal`, and the lines display fine. Using `tree /A` works fine also, and displays properly in Notepad with the default `Consolas` font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution based on the comment of @Ken White, as he said `tree /A` works fine and displays properly in Notepad with the default Consolas font.

```bat
@echo off
Set "PathFolder=C:\temp"
Set "LogFile=C:\temp\Tree_Result.txt"
Rem simply pipe tree output to skip the two lines in the header
Tree "%PathFolder%" /F /A | more +2>"%LogFile%" 
If Exist "%LogFile%" Start "" "%LogFile%"
```

The output is like this :

> ```
> C:\TEMP
> |   1155.tif
> |   check.txt
> |   filetest.txt
> |   InitJsonInSvc.dat
> |   InitJsonOutSvc.dat
> |   test.txt
> |   Tmp_Output.txt
> |   Tree_Output.txt
> |   Tree_Result.txt
> |   
> +---Exiland Backup
> |       parametre.ini
> |       
> \---Test
>     |   parametre.ini
>     |   
>     +---Exiland Backup
>     |       parametre.ini
>     |       
>     \---Nouveau dossier
>             b.txt
>             c.txt
>             parametre.ini
>             vide.ini
> ```

The second solution that i have created and tested on my windows 10 (32 bits) French version is like this Hybrid code :

```bat
<!-- :
@echo off
Title Replace unwanted Characters in the command Tree and save it into file by Hackoo 2019
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
::ÿþ
set "cp="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:." %%a in ('chcp') do set "cp=%%~a"
if not defined cp set "cp=850"
>nul chcp 65001

Set "PathFolder=C:\temp"
Set "TmpFile=C:\temp\Tmp_Output.txt"
Set "LogFile=C:\temp\Tree_Output.txt"

PowerShell ^
Tree "!PathFolder!" /F ^| Select-Object -Skip 2 ^| Set-Content !TmpFile! -Encoding unicode;
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:ReplaceString "!TmpFile!" "�" " ">"!LogFile!"
If Exist "!LogFile!" Start "" "!LogFile!"
endlocal
>nul chcp %cp%
exit /b
--->
<job id="ReplaceString">
    <script language="Vbscript">
    Dim fso,File,Char,ReplaceChar,ReadAll
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    InputFile=WScript.Arguments(0)
    Char=WScript.Arguments(1)
    ReplaceChar=WScript.Arguments(2)
    Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile, 1, False, -1)
    strData = oFile.ReadAll
    WScript.echo(Replace(strData,Char,ReplaceChar))
    </script>
</job>
```

So i got as output text like this :

> ```
> C:\TEMP
>     1155.tif
>     check.txt
>     filetest.txt
>     InitJsonInSvc.dat
>     InitJsonOutSvc.dat
>     test.txt
>     Tree_Result.txt
>
>     Exiland Backup
>         parametre.ini
>
>     Test
>         parametre.ini
>
>         Exiland Backup
>             parametre.ini
>
>         Nouveau dossier
>             b.txt
>             c.txt
>             parametre.ini
>             vide.ini
> ```